# how to branch from current branch and terminology for parent/source branch?

Tags: git

Will the following git command create a new branch off of the current branch?:

git branch my-new-branch

If so then what is the proper way to refer to the branch from which the new branch is created?  "root" branch, "source" branch, "parent" branch, etc?

Comment: Did you try it?  (Or look at the documentation / [a tutorial](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)?)

Comment: It creates a new branch and it does not depend on the current branch you have check out.. I don't understand your question.

Comment: I've done it once before when someone else showed me. I don't want to mess anything up so I'm trying to validate my understanding and see if I'm remembering correctly.

Comment: So if the branch command doesn't create a branch off of the current branch (say branch-x) then what command params would I use to branch the new branch off of branch-x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial Oliver linked in comments is pretty good, but I'll try to summarize. I will give you a bit of the git "theory," though, because a lot of git quirks make more sense if you know a bit about what's going on underneath.

`git branch my-branch` will create a new branch. That branch is really just a reference, though: **it points to a commit**. When you initially create a new branch, it points to whatever commit you were on when you created the branch. You can then checkout the new branch with `git checkout my-branch`. Alternatively, `git checkout -b my-branch` does both at once.

The "a branch is just a reference to one commit" thing is pretty unintuitive. The reason this works is that **each commit saves references to its parent commit(s)**. So you can trace a branch just by following parent commits back. Because of that, I'd call the original branch the "parent" branch: if you trace the new branch all the way back, its parent commit is from the original branch.

Comment: Thanks Canary. So if I'm currently on my-branch-x and then submit the following command: 

git checkout -b my-branch-y

Then the command above will essentially create the new branch my-branch-y off of my-branch-x?